# I try to use v-for to get the data key

Tags: vuejs3, v-for

Such as the Title, I try to create a menu that I use v-for to get array items and keys. Then I need the keys to create the second layer menu.

```
const localSite = ref('us')

const products = ref({})
const softwares = ref({})

const menuShow = ref({})


const menuTxt = ref({
  "us": {
    "products": "Products",
    "softwares": "Software"
  }
})
```

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">

        <div class="flex">
          <div v-for="( item, dataKey ) in menuTxt[localSite]" class="menu-item">
            <button class="text-white" :data-category="dataKey" @click="slideDown(dataKey)">
              {{ item }} 
              <font-awesome-icon icon="angle-down" />
            </button>

            <div class="text-box menu-content"> 
              <p v-for="itemA in dataKey">{{itemA}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I think the 'dataKey' is a variable which is the vue data Object.
But I can always get the wrong result.
What shoul I do ?

Comment: iterating over an object is a bit tricky, I'd suggest using an array and add the key as a property. The other option is to use a Map: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-vuejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to access the `products` and `softwares` properties by using the `dataKey` in the template. This is not possible the way you are doing it as it's referring to the key of `menuTxt`.

I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-d83uul?file=src/App.vue) to show a different kind of approach. Defining the child menu items along with it's parent in the same object. This also makes it more readable.